# SignalR strongly typed hub TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm encountering a TypeLoadException when I use a strongly typed hub. My interface is:

```
public interface IClientCallback
{
    void callback<T>(T msg, string eventType);
    void test(string msg, string eventType); 
}
```

All the methods are inside a single interface, and the interface does not inherit from any other interface.

My Hub class is:

```
public class ServiceHub : Hub<IClientCallback>
{
    public static readonly string ServiceHubName = "ServiceHub";

    public void Register(string name, string eventType)
    {
        Clients.All.test("hello", "world");
    }
}
```

When I use my client app to invoke the Register method on the hub, on the Hub application I receive an exception when it is at Clients.All.test(...):

> TypeLoadException Method 'callback' in type
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.TypedClientBuilder.IClientCallbackImpl'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.TypedClientBuilder,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have
>   an implementation.

I haven't been able to narrow down what exactly is causing this exception to be thrown. A little help or suggesting would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

It took couple hours of debugging to work out that the problem is in generic method definition. It seems like it simply doesn't supported.

So as a workaround it's possible to change the type of `msg` parameter to `object` and make `callback` method not generic. After this change everything should be working.

I wish Microsoft at least would add a warning about this limitation to the documentation.

Comment: It's a shame that Microsoft won't be implementing support for generics in the client interfaces. This workaround, however dirty it feels, does indeed work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like SignalR is using reflectionto find wich classes implements `IClientCallback` to instantiate it, but found nothing